# Using node.js async and require to fetch multiple urls

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Good day -- I've conducted many queries on this subject but can't find a good example that fits my situation.

Goal: To call multiple urls using request and async (these urls are different, some are xml and some are json), with the ability to scale the amount of links, with the end result of passing the data to the view for parsing.

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var async = require('async');

var bis;

var url_bis = {
  url: 'https://www.bis.org/list/cbspeeches/index.rss',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback_bis(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    bis = "";
    parseString(body, function (err, result) {
        bis = result;
        bis = bis["rdf:RDF"]["item"];
    });
  }
}

var doj;

var url_doj = {
  url: 'http://www.justice.gov/feeds/opa/justice-news.xml',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback_doj (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    doj = "";
    parseString(body, function (err, result) {
        _doj = result;
        doj = _doj.rss.channel[0].item;

    });
  }
}   

function feed_doj() {
    request(url_doj, callback_doj);
}
function feed_bis() {
    request(url_bis, callback_bis);
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

async.parallel({
    bis: feed_bis,
    doj: feed_doj

}, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results)
    // how to get the bis/doj response here in results?
});

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I dont know the the module `async`, but could you not simple store the response of each request in a global variable?

Comment: I did attempt that on the first variation without async, but it seemed that when I would refresh the page the data would not be passed to the view unless I refreshed twice. I'm not sure why it was behaving that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async needs to know when you've finished each task. To achieve this, the tasks are called with arguments which are callback functions. Your task functions, `feed_doj` and `feed_bis`, should call the callback functions. This is also the standard way of getting the output from the tasks - don't use global functions, it's widely considered bad form. Do this instead:

```
function feed_bis(callback) {
  function callback_bis(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        parseString(body, function (err, result) {
        var bis = result["rdf:RDF"]["item"];
        callback(null, bis);
      });
    }
  }
  request(url_bis, callback_bis);
}

// And same again for doj
```

Once the `callback` functions have been called for both bis and doj, the main callback will be called with arguments `(err, result)`; `err` will be `null` because you haven't done anything to handle error cases, and `result` will be an object with properties named `bis` and `doj`.

Answer (score 2):

This is super-easy with promises and the `Promise.all()` function:

```
var request = require('request-promise');

var calls = [
  request({ url: 'http://...', headers: { ... } }),
  request({ url: 'http://...', headers: { ... } }),
  // ...as many more as you want...
];

Promise.all(calls).then(function(results) {
  // do something with results[0]
  // do something with results[1]
});
```

The `Promise` API is native in newer versions of JS, and can be easily polyfilled in older JS engines, so it reduces the need for helper libs like `async`.

This example runs all the requests in parallel. `Promise.all()` waits for them all to finish, then gives you an array of results matching the original requests. Note also use of the `request-promise` module, which just piggybacks on top of the `request` module, but returns a promise instead of taking a callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the parallel method included in the  async module,you just push all request in an array and then implement this: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/README.md#parallel it is designed to execute a final callback when all processes end.